# Intermitant DefinitionInvalidException with windows forms ReportViewer 2008

Tags: reportviewer

I've got some RDL using it in a (windows forms) .net 2.0 app.

When user clicks around in app, rdl is reloaded into report viewer.
For the same RDL I sometimes get the error, sometimes not.

When I run my app debugging in Visual Studio it never gets the error.
Immediately after running, I launch the exe from the bin folder and now I get errors (but only 50% of the time the report gets refreshed)

The Exception occurs when I call ReportViewer.RefreshReport

I've looked through the RDL at every place where there is a minOccurs and they are all either "0" or "1".

Interestingly if I call Application.DoEvents() immediately before I call RefreshReport I can but the amount of time the error happens down to 5%... but it still occasionally happens!

The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
, An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
, The value for the 'minOccurs' attribute is invalid - The value for the 'minOccurs' attribute must be xsd:nonNegativeInteger..
 (DefinitionInvalidException)
Stack Trace:
Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. ---> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: The value for the 'minOccurs' attribute is invalid - The value for the 'minOccurs' attribute must be xsd:nonNegativeInteger..
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader reader, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(Stream stream, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.RmlValidatingReader..ctor(XmlTextReader textReader, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, String targetRDLNamespace)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.RmlValidatingReader.CreateReader(XmlTextReader upgradedRDLReader, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, String targetRDLNamespace)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.Phase1(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] definition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, String& description, String& language, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.CreateIntermediateFormat(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] definition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] reportDefinition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, String& reportDescription, String& reportLanguage, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] reportDefinition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] reportDefinition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.StoredReport.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.StoredReport.get_Snapshot()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContext context, Boolean rebuild, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.CompileReport()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
ReportViewer.RefreshReport
```

Doing this seemed to fix it.

```
Application.DoEvents()
ReportViewer.LocalReport.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Evidence)
```